# How to access checkbox form values after hitting the submit button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose you have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="clicked">

  <input type="checkbox" value="yes">yes<br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="no">no<br>

  <input type="button" onclick="Display()" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<p id="change"></p>

<script>

function Display() {

    var clicked = document.getElementById("clicked").value;
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = clicked;
} 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You want the Javascript to make the value of the checked box appear on screen once submit is clicked, but it keeps printing 'undefined' so obviously it's not accessing the form correctly.  What's the problem?

Comment: you need to check the checkbox and not the form id

Comment: do you want pure javascript or can u use jquery

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="clicked">

  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="yes">yes<br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="no">no<br>

  <input type="button" onclick="Display()" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<p id="change"></p>

<script>

function Display() {

    var clicked = document.getElementById("cb1").checked;
    var clicked2 = document.getElementById("cb2").checked;
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = " yes : " +clicked;
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML += "<br/> no : " + clicked2;
} 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

see here https://jsfiddle.net/mbkj6zv4/

Comment: What if it's `cb2` that's checked?